# Forcing Facebook Open Graph info on an unpublished page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Wondering if anyone out there has a clue if this is possible:  I run a large international site that often schedules blog posts in advance, for example, when it's 2am my time, it's 8am somewhere in the world and we want to have a blog go live then.  We simultaneously promote via FB and other social sites...scheduling those as well.

Unfortunately, because the blog is unpublished, the FB schedule scrapes "Access Denied" info and this stays sticky, even after the blog becomes live.  Thus, currently, I have to manually rescrape at 2am using the FB /tools/debug URL.  Not ideal.

We can't publish the blog early, as often the info is sensitive and we don't want something leaking out.  Is there any way to either force a FB rescrape when a blog is published OR can I set up the FB share with the right data in advance, despite the page being "Access Denied"?

Note:  I tried the obvious, which is to publish the blog for a few seconds, scrape the right info, then unpublish.  That works, but we end up with the blog live in the system longer than we want because of extensive load caching.  It's not practical to do this each time we post a blog.

I don't have any code to add here because this is a process question, but I'm hoping there's some code I can ADD to the page, something that will "ping" the FB rescrape when the blog switches from unpublished to live.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: No, there is nothing that _automatically_ makes Facebook re-scrape a URL. You can trigger a rescrape via API; But I don't think that affects posts that have already been made (even scheduled ones) - if you want to refresh the "share attachment" of a link post, you have to do it manually via the FB UI. I think you should rather move away from the FB scheduled posts functionality, and set up something on your end that makes the post, "live", once the article in your blog is publicly available, at the desired publishing time.

Comment: Thanks for the info, that's good to know.  I wonder how others have solved this -- seems like I can't be the only one.  It's just nice to not need to log in over the weekend or at all hours of the night.

Comment: Well as I said, a cron on your end that makes the posts at the desired time without relying on scheduling would be one option. Another could be to make the content available to the scraper up-front, recognizing it by its User-Agent - but since anyone can fake the same user agent when making a request, that could expose the information before you want them to be "public" - so that is rather an option only for cases in which that would not matter much.